# group rows data frame by multiple ranges of same column

Tags: r

Given this data:

```
id <- c("1","1", "1","2","2","2","3","3","3","4","4","4","5","5","5","6","6","6")
value <- c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8","9","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17","18")
value2 <- c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8","9","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17","18")
value3 <- c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8","9","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17","18")
df <- data.frame(id, value, value2, value3)
```

I would like to group the rows in two groups by multiple ranges (group1: 1-2 and 5-6; group2:3-4) and summarize by value so that the end result is as follows:

```
newname <- c("newname1", "newname2")
sumvalues <- c("114", "57")
sumvalues2 <- c("114", "57")
sumvalues3 <- c("114", "57")
df2 <- data.frame(newname, sumvalues, sumvalues2, sumvalues3)
```

I have tried the following when there is one single range of each new group (newname) but I can't figure out how to integrate several ranges into one new group

```
data_values_range <- data_values %>%                        # Aggregate values in range
  mutate(ranges = cut(group,
                      seq(1, 6, 1))) %>% 
  group_by(ranges) %>% 
  dplyr::summarize(sumvalues = sum(value)) %>% 
  as.data.frame()
data_values_range
```

in the case that there were more than one columns other than id, I would like that the end result shows the sum of the value of those columnes grouped by the new groups

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use

```
library(dplyr)# >= 1.1.0
df %>% 
 type.convert(as.is = TRUE) %>% 
group_by(newname = case_match(id, c(1,2, 5, 6) ~ 'newname1',
  c(3, 4)~ 'newname2',
  .default = 'other')) %>%
 select(-id) %>%
 reframe(across(where(is.numeric), ~  sum(.x, na.rm = TRUE), 
  .names = "sum{.col}"))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 2 × 4
  newname  sumvalue sumvalue2 sumvalue3
  <chr>       <int>     <int>     <int>
1 newname1      114       114       114
2 newname2       57        57        57
```

Comment: many thanks! what if there would be another column for which I also want the sum of its values grouped by column newname? is there a way to get the sum groupped by column new name of all other columns?

Comment: thanks for the update!

What is scaping me is to install the latest version of dplyr. I am using this: install.packages("remotes")
remotes::install_github("tidyverse/dplyr")

but then the packaged version keep being 1.0.10

Comment: @AyozeAlfageme you may have to update your R version

Comment: thanks! it works now.

However, I have added another column to the initial example but I can't get a tabble 2 x 3 with the sums of the other two columns. I will modify the initial question

Comment: now that I have modified the question I have unaccepted the other solution (which worked too). I think I initially accepted yours before the update.

Comment: @AyozeAlfageme based on your update, I get the same expected output as you showed

Answer (score 0):

You may create a named list of groups that you want to create. Get them in long format and join with original `df` to `sum` for each unique `name`.

```
library(tidyverse)

groups <- list(newname1 = c(1, 2, 5, 6), newname2 = c(3, 4))

enframe(groups, value = "new_value") %>%
  unnest(new_value) %>%
  inner_join(df, join_by(new_value == id), multiple = "all")  %>%
  summarise(value = sum(value), .by = name)

#   name     value
#  <chr>    <int>
#1 newname1   114
#2 newname2    57
```

**data**

I am not sure why the numbers are stored as characters in the dataframe `df`. Using `type.convert` will change them to numbers.

```
df <- type.convert(df, as.is = TRUE)
```

Comment: many thanks! what if there would be another column for which I also want the sum of its values grouped by column newname? is there a way to get the sum groupped by column new name of all other columns?